# How to notify ViewModel when properties binded to an ObservableCollection change?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using a HierarchicalDataTemplate to build a menubar that will have MenuItems that are checkable. In my ViewModel, I create an ObservableCollection of a class called MenuItemModel, then bind the ObservableCollection in my View. I can build the menu along with its submenus, but I can't figure out how to tell the ViewModel which MenuItem is checked.

I've tried using the INotifyPropertyChanged in the MenuItemModel but I could not figure out how to send that information to the ViewModel. After much googling, I've come to the conclusion this isn't the proper approach and I only need to use the INotifyPropertyChanged in the ViewModel. I'm a WPF newbie so still learning the do's and don'ts. I've found most of the code below on StackOverflow and have managed to adapt it to to my needs but I'm still trying to wrap my head around how it works. The code below will create a menu "Main Menu" with 3 submenus "SubMenu1", "SubMenu2", and "SubMenu3" where they are all checkable. That being said, here are my questions:

1. How/where do I implement the OnPropertyChanged event in the ViewModel when a MenuItem is checked/unchecked?
2. How can I access model properties of the MenuItem that was checked/unchecked?

```
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemsObservableCollection}">
                <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable"  Value="{Binding IsCheckable}" />
                        <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick"  Value="{Binding IsCheckable}" />
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked"  Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </Style>
                </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubMenuItemsObservableCollection}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </Menu.ItemTemplate>
            </Menu>
```

```
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            AddMenuItems();
        }

        private void AddMenuItems()
        {
            var subMenu = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel>
            {
                new MenuItemModel { Header = "SubMenu1" },
                new MenuItemModel { Header = "SubMenu2"},
                new MenuItemModel { Header = "SubMenu3"}
            };            

            MenuItemsObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel>
            {
                new MenuItemModel { Header = "Main Menu", SubMenuItemsObservableCollection = subMenu }
            };
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel> MenuItemsObservableCollection { get; set; }



    }
```

```
class MenuItemModel
    {
        public MenuItemModel()
        {
        }

        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public bool IsCheckable { get; set; } = true
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = false;

        public ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel> SubMenuItemsObservableCollection { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: MenuItemModel needs to implement INPC too as ViewModel

Comment: Yes, it's true you need to implement INPC, but if you want menu item in your viewmodel on checked/unchecked then you need to write a command and pass a command parameter such as : 
**<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.MenuItemCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}" /> 
<Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />**  Code must be written in your menu item style. Let me know in case if you want more details about.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying just not sure how to do it. DataContext.MenuItemCommand would be a method defined in the ViewModel? If you could show an example of how to create that method I would really appreciate it. Ultimately, i'm trying to get the Key property of the MenuItemModel that was checked/unchecked.

Comment: There are thousands of thousands examples for MVVM and Command even here on stackoverflow. Start a simple search